# Get Year of CreatedBy date in a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated column in SharePoint 2007. I want it to return the year of the CreatedBy column date and set the day to be 1 and the month to be January the data type returned by the formula is of type Date.

Any ideas how I can do this? 
=YEAR([Created]) does not seem to work as expected.

Thanks
Nav

Comment: Thanks Marek question edited to clarify that I want to return the year of the Created column and set the month to January and the Day to 01

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=DATE(YEAR([Created]),1,1)`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use =CONCATENATE(YEAR([Created])), it represents the year as plain text

Comment: This actually is no solution for the problem (getting a date of 1/1/yyyy) but I think most people just want to have the year in an extra column. Then you should use the formula in this answer. It still works in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Another solutionn = TEXT (created,"yyyy')